# How to play sound located in different folder in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I can access and play file named "Song.mp3" located in the root directory of my project but when I put it into "assets" directory I got error.

Here is my project directory:

```
- Test
-- src
--- Homeview.mxml
-- assets
--- Song.mp3
-- Song.mp3
```

I can access and play Song.mp3 located in the root folder but I get error when I want to play assets/Song.mp3.

This works:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('../Song.mp3');
```

This does not:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('../assets/Song.mp3');
```

I get following Runtime error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/assets/Song.mp3
```

I think that Song.mp3 in the root directory get exported in the final swf file but assets/Song.mp3 does not. If that is the case is there a way to force Flex to export assets/Song.mp3?

Comment: Since it is not an embedded asset; it won't get exported at all.  IT is up to you to put the mp3 file in the proper location on your production server.  I think there may be a setting in Flash Builder that moves non embedded assets, or something similar, though.

Comment: My project is "Flex Mobile Project". Flex compile everything into native app for the targeted platform. So there are no web server. Is it possible to force Flex to export all files of 'assets' directory? I don't want to Embed all files as the main swf file would become very very large.

Comment: Yes, with a mobile project you can select assets to be included in your final IPA or APK files.  There is an option there in Flash Builder when performing the export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use file class i.e. File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvepath("your url")
or File.applicationDirectory.resolvepath("your url").Store it in File type variable;use the file.url or file.nativePath to access the file.
This will be able to retrieve your external file which is there in the applicaton folder.

Comment: What I was mainly doing wrong was placing the "assets" folders outside src folder. I figured out that I have to place my assets directory into src folder in order to export into the final project.

Comment: that is 100% true.. :) hope this helps someone else too!